# ios Facebook login dialog encoding issue

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, encoding

anyone experienced this before?
the facebook login form displays weird characters sometimes. It does not happen consistently, but it happens pretty often on a device.
any ideas why it happens?

[image]

Comment: It is really strange...Can you add some code,  that you are trying to open the FBDialog?

Comment: what is the locale of the app and device?

Comment: the locale for both the app and the device is 'English' [Localization native development region - changed it to 'United States' from the dropdown], and it happens rarely, but it happens.

Comment: Facebook *_face; [_face authorize:_permissions]; static NSString* kDialogBaseURL = @"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/"; - this is an older SDK version that the customer has. we might upgrade it, but for now I am stuck with it.